# What causes this error: "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query"?

Tags: sql-server, tridion

I occasionally get this error message on a Tridion 2011 SP1 development machine:

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
>   Unable to save Schema (tcm:0-0-0). A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ORG_ITEMS_FINDUNIQUENESSCONFLICTS".EDA_ORG_ITEMS_FINDUNIQUENESSCONFLICTS

Searching for the error message here on StackOverflow suggests rewriting the stored procedure to not use temporary tables. Without doing that, does anyone know how to get rid of this error message?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982854

Comment: Without understanding what your stored procedure does, it is going to be really tough for anyone to answer anything other than "add more memory" or "don't use temp tables." In fact without the observation you made we wouldn't even know about the temp tables. Maybe you could share the code or at least a rough skeleton of what it is doing? Also indicate if you've reviewed the execution plan to determine if there is anything that stands out?

Comment: The problem occurs on a standard released product (Tridion 2011 SP1) for which I didn't write the stored procedures. So I think I'll upgrade my SQL Server 2008 R2 to SP1 (or CU4) to see if it solves the problem. Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you updates statistics and rebuilt your indexes recently? I seem to recall seeing similar errors in poorly maintained SDL Tridion CM databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is hard to be certain that the upgrade fixed it, the problem hasn't occurred anymore after upgrading SQL Server 2008 R2 to SP1.